# Firefox cross origin images

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, fabricjs

Whenever I set the crossorigin attribute on an image firefox don't render the image.

```
<img crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I'm using fabric.js wich sets this attribute for me via JavaScript. I need to be able to render cross origin images. It works fine in Chrome and even IE. It seams as if Firefox previously have had [some problems with CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299551/firefox-cross-domain-images-are-tainted) and I'm not sure if it's related, but I can seem to find any solutions to the problem.

Since I am using a PHP proxy I have set the the headers:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

This works fine in Chrome and even IE.

So do any of you know why the image is not displayed; not even in the img tag? I've sent [a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1183014) but in the mean time maybe someone knows a workaround?

Comment: Are you setting the cors before the src attribute ?

Comment: Since I don't set the attribute myself (fabricjs does this in JS) I don't have any power of the order which it's set. The order doesn't matter, still same result.

Comment: It does, actually affect the outcome. In Firefox, if I set the ``crossOrigin`` property first, and then the ``src``, the security is lifted. It is not when the order is reversed. In Chrome, both work.

Answer (score 0):

Long shot here, not certain if this will help you at all.
Perhaps Firefox needs certain headers to load cross-origin data/images? 
In case you work in apache/unix environment, you can try to add the following in your htaccess, and see if it helps you in any way.

```
# Send the CORS header for images when browsers request it.
#
# https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image
# https://blog.chromium.org/2011/07/using-cross-domain-images-in-webgl-and.html

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(bmp|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)$">
            SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

In case you need to "read" image data from another domain, make sure they issue cors headers

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but in my experience FabricJS does not set the crossOrigin attribute.  In my app, I'm setting this manually.  But maybe I'm doing it wrong...

One other thought is that I believe the attribute is case sensitive - the 'O' should be capitalized.  In your example above it is all lower case.

Mozilla (the maker of Firefox) has a very detailed explanation on how to use this as well.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Lastly, as has been said elsewhere, including the point @andrew is highlighting, the domain that serves the image needs to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.  If this is not set by the server that hosts the image, your canvas will always be tainted.  If you control that server, then follow @andrew's suggestion (for Apache) or other examples for other server platforms and ensure the header is set.  You can verify it is set via the network panel of the developer tools or a packet sniffer.

Please let us know what you find to be the solution to this - CORS can be tricky and confusing, particularly in Fabric and Canvas, and more solutions on the web to the solutions is very helpful to those that need some guidance.

Comment: actually I think that the inline `crossorigin` attribute might be set without camelCase, but the DOM attribute (accessible via js) needs it.

Comment: I know I am setting it via camelCase and have success.  I have tested Firefox and have extensive error tracking which suggests all is working for my visitors.  Just my experience.

Comment: Yes because HTML is case-insensitive. But in every documents it's referred as `crossorigin'.